# Ошибка в подсчёте сложного процента

Tags: python, python-3.x

Условие задачи: 
Процентная ставка по вкладу составляет P процентов годовых, которые прибавляются к сумме вклада через год. Вклад составляет X рублей Y копеек. Определите размер вклада через K лет.

Формат вывода:
Программа должна вывести два числа: величину вклада через K лет в рублях и копейках. Дробное число копеек по истечение года отбрасывается. Перерасчет суммы вклада (с отбрасыванием дробных частей копеек) происходит ежегодно.

Проблема:
Не получается увидеть ошибку подсчёта. По идее не отбрасывается дробная часть копеек но не вижу этого в коде. Прошу помощи!

Код:

```
p = float(input()) # Годовая процентная ставка
x = int(input())   # К-во рублей вклада
y = int(input())   # К-во копеек вклада
k = int(input())   # Строк вклада
i = 0              # Счётчик лет

kopT = (x * 100) + y  # Переводим сумму вклада в копейки
kop = 0               # Сумма вклада с процентами по прошествию і года
while i <= k:         

    kop = int(kopT + kopT / 100 * p) # Сумма вклада + годовой процент
    x = kop // 100                   # К-во рублей 
    y = int(kop % 100)               # К-во копеек без дробной части
    kopT = (x * 100) + y             # Переводим сумму вклада с проц. в копейки
    i += 1                           # Добавляем год

print(x, y)                          # Выводим сумму в рублях и копейках итого
```

Comment: Комментариев нет, что означают переменные непонятно. Вряд ли кто-то захочет тут разбираться.

Comment: Спасибо за дельный совет! Буду учитывать...

Comment: @IgorSalm попробуйте обрезать дробную часть не через `int(kop%100)`, а через `(kop%100)//1`. Возможно, проблема в неправильном округлении при явном приведении типа

Comment: Не помогло(( Заменил int(kop%100) на (kop%100)//1 и без результата.

Comment: Может привести пример входных данных, для которых наблюдается ошибка, значение, которое вы ожидаете получить, и значение, которое реально получается? Я погонял код на паре примеров, пока не вижу проблему.

Comment: @Xander входные данные: р = 12, x = 179, y = 0, k = 5.  Правильний вывод: 315 43. Мой код по указаним входним данним виводит: 353 28.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сами вычисления у вас правильные.

Проблема возникает из-за того, что условие

```
while i <= k:
```

у вас допускает i равные 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 - то есть цикл у вас выполняется 6 раз вместо 5.

Замените строчку на

```
while i < k:
```

и в результате получите ожидаемые 315 43

И кстати, задачи с рублями и копейками часто решать гораздо проще, если не таскать весь код с собой рубли, а сразу перевести их в копейки, считать всё только в копейках и только перед выводом привести их обратно к рублям и копейкам:

```
p = 12 # Годовая процентная ставка
x = 179   # К-во рублей вклада
y = 0   # К-во копеек вклада
k = 5   # Строк вклада

sy = 100 * x + y  # Сумма только в копейках

for i in range(k):
    sy += int(sy * p / 100)

print(sy // 100, sy % 100)
```

Comment: Работает))) Большое спасибо за помощь!!!